# When using autocomplete, Is it possible to post above two data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getCustomer() {
        $('#CST_Idx_BI').autocomplete({            
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("JsonGetCustomerName","Customer")',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: { Keyword: $('#CST_Idx_BI').val(), CST_Idx: $('#CST_Idx_BI').val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(
                            $.map(data, function (item, i) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.CST_Name,
                                    value: item.CST_Idx
                                }                                
                            })
                            );
                    }
                });
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).val(ui.item.question);
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#CST_Name_BI').val(ui.item.label);
            },
        })
    }

</script>
```

When somebody inputs data(Regardless of whether numeric:CST_Inx or character:Keyword), I want to get the result they want.
But if somebody input data, Keyword = the data, CST_Idx = the data.
So I can't get any result... in my case, How can I solve this?

Is it possible to post above two data in same input element?
I mean, Regardless of whether CST_Inx or Keyword, when somebody inputs data in same input element, I want to get same result.

***Umm, I've changed my post many times. In advance Sorry. I didn't check my error carefully bofore posting this. Sorry.***

Comment: By not working, do you mean the ajax request is not being made?

Comment: @Greg Borbonus, yes... I mean when ajax request, `$('#CST_Idx_BI').val()` data type

Comment: Are you saying that ('#CST_Idx_BI').val() is null or empty when it's a numeric value? and the ajax works, but the keyword is not populated correctly? If so, please show the html you're using in conjunction.

Comment: @GregBorbonus, I'm sorry, I didn't check my error carefully. I've just updated my post

Comment: I'm sorry, after the edits, it's still very hard to understand what you want to do, can you make a JSFiddle or link to an example, maybe we can figure it out through that